# When creating an object using a constructor while building an array, do you need to include the semicolon?

Tags: javascript, arrays

So, I'm coding in javascript and I'm essentially building a database js file, which every entry in the database will be a custom object.

Here's my code so far:

```
class DatabaseItem {
    constructor(val) {
        this.val = val;
    }
    contructor(val, traits) {
        this.val = val;
        this.traits = traits;
    }
    returnID() {
        return val;
    }
}

var database = [
    [
        const vol00 = new DatabaseItem("00");,
        []
    ]
    [][][][][][][][][]
];
```

Is the above code correct, or do I need to remove the semi-colon after the item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the variable declaration entirely, and just put the value. And you need commas between all the arrays.

```
var database = [
    [
        new DatabaseItem("00"),
        []
    ],
    [],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]
];
```

If you need to declare a variable for that object, do it before creating the container array.

```
const vol00 = new DatabaseItem("00");
var database = [
    [
        vol00,
        []
    ],
    [],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]
];
```